# Edit system files on windows or linux

Tags: sd-card, linux, mount

i've messed up the `/etc/profile` file and now i can't login to the rpi.
Is there a way to edit this file on windows or linux ?

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the sd card and edit the file on another computer. That's the easiest way to go around it.

Comment: when i read the card from windows i cant see the file

Comment: Are you able to see other files? Or none at all? You should end up seeing two partitions (I think) and you will have to "mount" the second partition from the sd card.... and that is "if" windows is able to mount ext3/ext4 (or whatever formatting) the partition has. I have no idea if that's possible with windows these days (would think it's still not possible, but won't assume.. it's been more than 15 years since I used windows semi-seriously so don't know the state of affairs for this). I'd say: try to mount it on a linux box.

Comment: Just in case: not that you need to install linux on a computer to do this. If you are in extreme need, you could just use a live CD or live USB to boot on linux without touching a single bit from your windows installation on the computer.

Comment: You do _not_ need to install linux to read linux file systems. There  is software available to access linux fs on windows. Just search _how to access linux fs on windows_ on google @eftshift0 , Hbib.

Comment: I think it's clear enough from my comments, but just in case: In no way did I imply that linux _has_ to be installed in order to be able to read/write from the sdcard. I  said: 1 I don't know if it's possible to do it from windows. 2 In case of extreme need (For example, as in, "I don't have the time to sit down to download software from who knows where on internet in order to mount on windows and follow who knows how many instructions to get it done), it can be done by starting linux from a live Cd or live USB so that the windows installation doesn't get busted and i can move on with my life.

Comment: Your comments and clarifications belong in your answer, not the comments. Please edit your answer accordingly.